# Как получить из ajax запроса переменную в PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

HTML

```
<form id="pay">
  <div class="product basket-btn">
    <button class="basket-btn__pay">Оплатить</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

JS

```
$("#pay").on("submit", function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    const totalPrice = parseFloat(total.textContent);
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'pay.php',
      data: totalPrice,
      success: function(response, statusText, status) {
        console.log('Запрос успешно отправился, получаем ответ', response);
      }
    });
  });
```

Я пытаюсь получить в php так, но ничего не получается
PHP

```
 if($_POST['totalPrice']) {
    $msg = $_POST['totalPrice'];
    echo "Данные приняты";
  } else {
    echo "Данных нет";
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$("#pay").on("submit", function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    const totalPrice = parseFloat(total.textContent);
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'pay.php',
      data: {totalPrice: totalPrice},
      success: function(response, statusText, status) {
        console.log('Запрос успешно отправился, получаем ответ', response);
      }
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 2):

data: { totalPrice: totalPrice }